# Assign variable on array with loop in Bash Script

Tags: bash

I have four variables, seen below:

```
p0="something"
p1="something"
p2="something"
p3="something"
p4="something"

var=()
```

I want to put each of the variables into an array with a loop, in a way so that I can call the value of the variable within the array. It should look something like this:

```
var=($p0 $p1 $p2 $p3 p$4)
```

I already tried this:

```
for i in {0..4}
do
    $var[$i]="\$p$i"
done
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use namerefs (Bash 4.3+) and the `${!prefix@}` parameter expansion:

```sh
declare -n varname
for varname in "${!p@}"; do
    var+=("$varname")
done
```

This makes `varname` behave as if it were the variable its name it has as its value; `"${!p@}"` expands to all variable names with prefix `p`. This is also a drawback of this method: it fails if there are other variables whose name starts with `p`.

A more explicit way would be to loop over the variable names like this:

```sh
for varname in p{0..4}; do
```